# C++11 std::forward a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have a `Signal` class in my application that provides classes with an option to expose events (same as in .NET).

The class works and all is well.

Yesterday I saw [this SO question (and its answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38707593/2523211) and was familiarized with `std::forward`.

I decided to try to use it in my code so I changed every `std::function<void(Args...)>` to `std::function<void(Args&&...)>` and in the raise function (the `operator()`) I used the same logic I saw in the above link so now the function takes `Args&&...args` and the callback uses `std::forward<Args>(args)...`

Here's a simplified version of my Signal class (with some changes to make it a good example):

```
template<typename... Args> class Signal
{
public:
    int operator+=(const std::function<void(Args&&...)>& func)  {
        int token = getNewToken();
        m_subscribers.emplace(token, func);
        return token;
    }

    void operator()(Args&&... args) {
        for (auto it : m_subscribers) {
            it.second(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    }

private:
    std::map<int, std::function<void(Args&&...)>> m_subscribers;
};

int main() {
    int* six = new int(6);
    int seven = 7;

    Signal<int*> e1;
    e1 += [](int* x) { std::cout << *x; };

    Signal<int> e2;
    e2 += [](int x) { std::cout << x; };

    e1(&seven);
    e2(6);

    e1(six);  //Error C2664 'void Signal<int *>::operator ()(int *&&)': 
              //  cannot convert argument 1 from 'int *' to 'int *&&'
    e1(std::move(six)); //This is a workaround          
    return 0;
}
```

The issue I'm seeing is with classes (or `main` in this example) that try to raise events with pointers and I'm not sure how to solve this.

My main goal is to have the Signal class a general API and if the developers chose to use `Signal<int*>` I don't want him\her to raise with `std::move`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`T&&` is only a universal reference if `T` is a non-cv-qualified function template parameter. In your call operator:

```
void operator()(Args&&... args) {
```

`Args` isn't a template parameter of the function, it's a template parameter of the class. So for `Signal<int*>`, this `operator()` takes an rvalue reference to `int*`. Since `six` is an lvalue, that fails.

What you want is to provide the correct reference qualifications to `Signal`. Like so:

```
template<typename... Args>
class Signal
{
    using F = std::function<void(Args...)>; // NB: Just Args...
public:
    int operator+=(F func)  {
        int token = getNewToken();
        m_subscribers.emplace(token, std::move(func));
        return token;
    }

    void operator()(Args... args) {       // NB: just Args...
        for (auto& it : m_subscribers) {  // NB: auto&
            it.second(args...);
        }
    }

private:
    std::map<int, F> m_subscribers;
};
```

Note that forwarding `Args...` is questionable anyway. What if you had two subscribers? Once you forward the args once you can't really use them a second time.

The above will make `Signal<int*>` do what you expect. The `operator()` will just take an `int*`, which you can pass either an lvalue or an rvalue to.

Comment: @WernerErasmus Yes. If you have multiple subscribers, you can't forward the same arguments multiple times.

Comment: Thanks Barry, except for the `using F` part, this is the code I already use. So basically your answer is sort of "you can't and shouldn't use std::forward in this case"?

Comment: I'm more interested in how and if I can use std::forward with all types. I feel like I should read some more on it since the first paragraph of your answer was a bit nuclear to me...

Comment: @ZivS Unrelated to anything, I found the typo on "nuclear" to be hilarious.

Answer (score 1):

Barry's answer is correct, but perhaps not as clearly explained as it could be.

`&&` is only given its special treatment as a forwarding (or "universal") reference *when template parameter deduction occurs*. But there is no deduction occurring here:

```
Signal<int*> e1;  // `Args...` is explicitly `int*`
...
e1(six);          // `Args...` *has already been specified*
```

When template classes are instantiated, they are essentially transformed into normal classes that just happen to be written by the compiler. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28643646/1858225) for an example of what this might look like if written out in C++ code.

In C++14, there is *no* way to trigger template-parameter deduction of class templates without an auxiliary *function* (not a constructor):

```
template <typename Args...>
Signal<Args...> make_signal(Args&&...) { return Signal<Args...>; }
```

....But note that in your case, this makes no sense: you don't want to *infer* the types of your arguments when create the `Signal`, you want to *specify* them in advance.

(Note that in C++17, there *will* be support for [template argument deduction of class templates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r2.html). I assume this means that it will be possible to `forward` template-class arguments, though it's not immediately clear to me what the implications of doing such a thing would be.)

What you want to permit is for arguments to be forwarded *at call time*. This is actually reasonably simple:

```
template<typename... Args> class Signal
{
public:
    // .... skipping some code...

    template <typename... CallArgs>
    void operator()(CallArgs&&... args) {
        callback(std::forward<CallArgs>(args)...);
    }
};
```

....But, again, in your case this doesn't quite make sense, as noted in Barry's answer. You don't *want* to forward arguments if you have multiple callbacks, to prevent moving and re-using them.

It's possible to work around this by checking the size of `m_subscribers` and only using the `forward`ing code if it's `1`, and just passing the arguments as-is otherwise. However, this might lead to confusing behavior, since the way callbacks are invoked shouldn't generally depend on the state of your `Signal` object. So you could perhaps write a separate class, `SingletonSignal`, for callbacks that *must* be invoked with `forward`ed arguments (e.g. in case a callback wants to *transfer ownership* of an uncopyable object such as `unique_ptr`).